# TypeScript using Strapi types inappropriate strings

Tags: typescript, strapi

I am using the generated TS types with `npm run strapi ts:generate-types --verbose`. Problem is TypeScript complains about pretty much any attribute being a `StringAttribute` instead of `string | undefined`.

Error

> Type 'StringAttribute' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

Simplest example with the `alt` attribute

```
const { attributes: { name }} = ApiProductProduct;

return <img src={fromImageToUrl(image)} alt={name} />;
```

What shall I do to make TypeScript accept the types?